# Save a Stack Overflow post

Tags: bookmarks

This is probably won't be the dumbest questions I've ever asked but I found some posts in Stack Overflow that I want to keep as reference and would like to bookmark them to my account. How do I do that?

Comment: This is a question for [meta] not for [so].

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can mark them as bookmarks (the star-in-a-bookmark icon under the voting buttons). They will be then available in your profile, in "bookmarks" section.

Answer (score 34):

#### How to Bookmark / Save a question or answer:

[image: how to save a question and how to save an answer]

<sub>*Update: it's now possible to save answers as well!*</sub>

---

---

#### How to Access your Bookmarks / Saves:

[image: access saved questions: 1) Click profile icon, 2) Click Saves tab]

---

---

##### "Bookmarks" have changed to "Saves"

As of September 2022, Bookmarks have been renamed to Saves and have become much more powerful and advanced. [Read about all the new features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves).

One of the new features is to have Custom Lists to store the bookmarks/saves in. When bookmarking/saving a question or answer, a green banner will appear on top notifying you which List the post was saved to.

#### How to Change List / Create New List

Click on **Manage** after hitting Save:

[image: save popup]

You can also go to **Profile > Saves** and click on the **Create new list** blue button.

Comment: Can I ask what tool you used to create those images?

Comment: @DevsloveZenUML: Online Photoshop clone https://www.photopea.com/ -- took screenshots, manually edited in lots of visual flair, and wasted *tons* of hours :(