# Where are MY bookmarked questions or Lists on Stack Overflow? They're Not in My Profile

Tags: bookmarks, missing-features

I've saved important questions and answers on Stack Overflow, which is a part of Stack Exchange.  S.O. allows one to put these into lists which one can name uniquely.

Now I cannot find any of these lists.  They're not under Help the (?), not in the tutorial on using Stack Overflow.

Where are they {the saved Lists or Bookmarks or Whatever they're called}?

Since answered questions are a critical part of using Stack Overflow for me, can an icon be created somewhere so I can find my lists of Questions and Answers in something less than 45 minutes?  This would be a wonderful feature to have.

A similar answer is posted that these are available under "Bookmarks" in My Profile.  There are no Bookmarks listed in My profile.  Yes I do have these Lists but they're somewhere not referenced.

Here is the link to that Q/A:
[Save a SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125863/save-a-stack-overflow-post)

Comment: Please ask these types of questions on Meta Stack Overflow.